# Run multiple shell scripts in a single script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have 50 shell scripts: proc_0.sh, proc_500.sh, proc_1000.sh...proc_25000.sh.

Each of them perform same operation but on different files.

I would like to execute all these shell scripts in a single master shell script, one after another.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
#!/bin/bash/

cd $(pwd)

i=0

for i in {0..25000..500}
do
     chmod +x proc_${i}.sh
     bash proc_${i}.sh
done

exit
```

Now, I am not sure about this but it seems that these scripts are running in parallel or getting mixed up in some way. I say this because when I run a few of these scripts individually, they give correct results but not when run in the way mentioned above. It could also be that there might be a problem with the program these scripts are executing.

So, could anyone please tell me if this is the right way to run multiple shell scripts one after another? It would help me narrow down the problem.

Thanks

Comment: `{0..25000..500}` : is it `{0..500..25000}` that you wanted ? what about `seq 0 25000 500` ?

Comment: I wanted to go from 0 to 25000 with an interval of 500. This corresponds to the filenames. What would seq 0 25000 500 do exactly? Thanks.

Comment: try seq in a shell script

Comment: no, the {0..25000..500} bit works according to specs and is the best choice in this case. Do not use `seq` if you don't need it. It is not a build-in, it is slower, eats more resources and it is depricated.

Comment: @thom, who has deprecated `seq`?

Comment: You know that it is never a single person that deprecates something. My story is 477 characters too long for this commentfield but the  main thing is: When the (( )) arithmetic operators were introduced in bash, the use of 'seq' was strongly discouraged because of "some vulnerabilities" ( which i didn't bother about at that time so I don't remember why) and because this external was no longer needed. the `for (( ; ; ))` construction has "replaced" `seq`. Something is only really "deprecated" if it is  "end of life" which is, of course, very difficult to measure in a free software society.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is a bit messy how you are doing it.

```
#!/bin/bash/
```

Drop the last slash or it won't work

```
cd $(pwd)
```

this is the same as `cd .` .cd to the current directory is bogus. Delete this from your script.

```
i=0
```

You can delete this also: It is followed by a for loop which already initializes $i

```
 chmod +x proc_${i}.sh
```

You are explicitly setting the execute flag EVERY time this script runs. It does no harm but  once is enough.

```
bash proc_${i}.sh
```

You don't need to use the "bash" statement.  Regardless of this, it will not run because you forgot the path to your command. Unless you are running this from a directory like /usr/local/bin: Always use a path !

And no, your scripts are **not** running in parallel. You forgot to background them.

try this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {0..25000..500}
do
     /path/to/proc_${i}.sh &   #<- don't forget to replace "/path/to" with the
done                           #   real directory where the proc_ files reside

wait
```

This will get your computer flooded with your 50 processes at once.

run `top` to see them running.

It would be best if you had all these proc scripts together in one subdirectory exclusively and then run:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in "/path/to/procscripts/"*
do
    "$i" &
done

wait
```

This would make it more flexible and more easy on yourself.

Also making all your scripts executable could then be easier:

```
chmod a+x "/path/to/procscripts/"*
```

Comment: why wait is used here.. what will happen if i don't use wait here ??